# How to check SQL connection in C#.Net?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I want check my SQL server connection before to connect with DB, and I need to update the status of SQL Server connection in my GUI.

Here is the code I am checking SQL connection, but I couldn't able to get status frequently

**Scenario :**

- Stop the sql server service from services window
- Running the project and will show status "Connection Not Available"
- Start Sql server service and displaying "Connection Live"
- And Again Stop SQL server service and i am not getting the status as ""Connection Not
  Available". It's returning status as "Connection Live"
- **It's not getting to the catch block**

**Code:**

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool Flag = false;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))
            {
                con.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException s)
        {
            Flag = true;
            label1.Text = "Connection Not available";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Flag == false)
            {
                label1.Text = "Connection Live";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there server is unavailable, your application will hang while it tries to connect.  This should be run in a background worker and the status updated with a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your connection attempt in a `try..catch` (it should be using a `using` statement at the very least). [The precise location of a `try..catch` in your code depends somewhat on the structure of your code.]

It is unusual for an application to maintain whether a SQL Server is available. After all, it might be unavailable milliseconds after you test and display that it is available.